# How to send and receive data between a Wear OS smartwatch and a Windows PC

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I want to notify my employee's smartwatch (Wear OS by Google) when something goes wrong with a machine at the factory.
There is one Windows PC for management, and this PC holds the state of the machine. There are 10 smart watches in the factory.
There is a wireless LAN access point in the factory. The Windows PC and smartwatch are in the same network.

I think there are several methods, but I would like to know the optimal solution.

```
For example
1.The smartwatch directly refers to the DB in the PC.
2.Send and receive messages (JSON?) Between your PC and smartwatch
```

If I can know how to do it, I will try to develop it.

I develop Windows PC apps well, but I have rarely developed Android apps.
I'm not good at English. I asked a question in English because there is not much information in my mother tongue.
Sorry if I came off as rude.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Firebase Cloud Messaging!
It's great to send push-notifications to your Smartwatches - and it's free!

Link & Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Thanks you very much.
I'll look into FCM.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options here.

1. MQTT client-server https://mqtt.org/
2. Firebase cloud messaging https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

The option 1 (MQTT) is actually faster because it can run local at your LAN and doesn't depends on external service like firebase.

That means:

- MQTT notifies from your watch to your PC or opposite directly from LAN.
- Firebase Cloud Messaging have to notify the cloud service and then your watch will get the notification or opposite (if your LAN is connected to the internet).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Thanks you very much.
I'll look into MQTT.